# Add cms url suffix

Tags: magento-1.9, url, cms

Is there is any way to add cms url suffix??
In magento all cms pages are urls are:

```
www.domain.com/url_key
```

But can I add a url suffix to this url?? I want to make it like below:

```
www.domain.com/url_key.htm
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: please have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472000/magento-custom-url-rewrites-to-html-for-cms-pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can specify the `.htm` suffix in the `URL key` field of CMS pages.

Remember to adjust the footer links static block accordingly to that change.

Comment: I totally forget this one to check.. I did this for identifier but it was said that's `.` not supported and that why i did not test in on cms page. Thank you sir